# An unexpected effect appears when using django's Q

Tags: django, orm

In [25]: Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=('2020-04-28','2020-04-28'))&~Q(change__se__isnull=True)).count()
Out[25]: 8

In [26]: Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=('2020-04-28','2020-04-28'))&Q(change__se__isnull=False)).count()
Out[26]: 9
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFzMC.png)

I don't know what the difference is

Comment: I don't know why the results of the two query statements are different
If you can help me, thank you very much

Comment: In [35]: Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=('2020-04-28','2020-04-28'))).count()

Out[35]: 11

In [36]: Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=('2020-04-28','2020-04-28'))&~Q(change__se__isnull=True)).count()

Out[36]: 8

In [37]: Project.objects.filter(Q(change__date__date__range=('2020-04-28','2020-04-28'))&~Q(change__se__isnull=False)).count()

Out[37]: 2

Comment: Please format your question to distinguish code from output. Also, please include code and output, but not pictures of it.